# Github - Restrict pull requests to master from all branches except "develop" branch

Tags: git, github, githooks, pull-request

I'd like to allow pull requests to "master" only from "develop" branch.

As of now I can create a pull request from a "feature" branch to "master" and this is not the behavior I want.

Is it possible to enforce this?

Couldn't find a way to do that in github

Comment: I think this is not possible, as I can fork your repository, create new branch, name it like I want and then send PR. You'd probably have to create some custom hook on PR and check it there. What issue do you try to solve?

Comment: Continuous integration flow where I need the tests to pass before a PR is created . I want to hook the CI to the develop branch

Comment: Have you looked a branch permissions in github? https://confluence.atlassian.com/stash/using-branch-permissions-313460915.html#notfound

Comment: I think the only way is create a workflow file that only passes if the branch is `develop`, and add it to status check for `master`.